# Break out of a While...Wend loop

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop

I am using a While...Wend loop of VBA.

```
Dim count as Integer

While True
    count=count+1

    If count = 10 Then
        ''What should be the statement to break the While...Wend loop? 
        ''Break or Exit While not working
    EndIf
Wend
```

I don't want to use condition like `While count<=10...Wend

Answer (score 227, accepted):

A `While`/`Wend` loop can only be exited prematurely with a `GOTO` or by exiting from an outer block (`Exit sub`/`function` or another exitable loop)

Change to a `Do` loop instead:

```
Do While True
    count = count + 1

    If count = 10 Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Or for looping a set number of times:

```
for count = 1 to 10
   msgbox count
next
```

(`Exit For` can be used above to exit prematurely)

Comment: What's the difference between a `While` and a `Do While` please?

Comment: @GMSL while is basically a worse version of Do While.  The looping behavior is identical. https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-while-loop/

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to set a flag variable as a `Boolean` and then change that value based on your criteria.

```
Dim count as Integer 
Dim flag as Boolean

flag = True

While flag
    count = count + 1 

    If count = 10 Then
        'Set the flag to false         '
        flag = false
    End If 
Wend
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use an `And` clause in your `While` statement

```
Dim count as Integer
count =0
While True And count <= 10
    count=count+1
    Debug.Print(count)
Wend
```

Answer (score 0):

What about setting the 'While' test perameters in the loop so that the loop ends on the next iteration. For example...

```
OS = 0
While OS <> 1000 
OS = OS + 1 
If OS = 500 Then OS = 1000 
Wend
```

Ok, that's a totally pointless example but it shows the principle...