# VBA : Exit While in If

Tags: vba, excel, loops, while-loop

Ok, probably an easy one but I'm just starting to use this language and in this piece of code :

```
While DATA.Cells(1, i).value & "" <> ""
    If InStr(DATA.Cells(1, i).value, columnName) > 0 Then
        column = i
        Exit While
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

It looks like it's not the way to use Exit While ? How should I do it then ?

Comment: It's duplicated, but the question name is easy to someone else to find. @duDE

Comment: Your condition in the While statement puzzles me. Can you please try to describe what it is supposed to do?

Comment: While CELL.value is not empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `While/Wend` can only be exited prematurely with a `GOTO` or by exiting from an outer block (`Exit sub`/`function`/`another exitable loop`)

Change to a `Do` loop intead

```
Do While DATA.Cells(1, i).value & "" <> ""
If InStr(DATA.Cells(1, i).value, columnName) > 0 Then
    column = i
    Exit Do
End If
i = i + 1
Loop
```

Original answer from @Alex K.
[Break out of a While...Wend loop in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200834/break-out-of-a-while-wend-loop-in-vba#answers-header)